# How to cycle a coroutine every 10 seconds to accelerate a scrolling background?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm an absolute newbie in Unity, and I'm trying to create a 2D game that requires a scrolling background that accelerates every 10 seconds. I'm having trouble getting the code to work

I've tried to set up a Coroutine, but it seems to call the function every frame, instead of every 10 seconds

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ScrollingBackground : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float bgSpeed = 5;
    public Renderer bgRend;
    public float increment = 2f;

    private void Start()
    {
         StartCoroutine(Accelerate());
    }

    void Update()
    {
        bgRend.material.mainTextureOffset += new Vector2(0f, bgSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        StartCoroutine(Accelerate());
    }

     private IEnumerator Accelerate()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            bgSpeed = increment * Time.deltaTime;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(10f);
            Debug.Log("Getting Faster!");
            Debug.Log("OnCoroutine: " + (int)Time.time);
        }
    }
}
```

Not only is the background speed going very slowly (only up to around 0.3 and stuck), I can't seem to make this work. Thank you for you help !

Comment: If you want it to change every 10s you could use invokerepeating

Answer (score 2):

First, you should only start your coroutine once, such as in `Start` - instead, you're starting it every frame, so the speed is going to get stuck.

Second, is your texture [scaled](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material-mainTextureScale.html) at all? This may affect how it looks when you're adjusting the offset directly, and thus why it appears to be stuck at 0.3 even though your increment is `2f` here.

Finally, note that [`deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) is the time since the last *frame*, so using to adjust your speed rather than adding a constant is going to produce strange results dependent on performance. It's useful when applying the speed to movement, but not the acceleration based on this game logic.

Comment: Hello, thanks your help !
Yeah, obviously the coroutine was in the wrong place. 
I replaced the deltaTime and replaced it by the increment, as it makes more sense as you pointed out.

FInally, regarding the texture, it was scaled but I think the problem comes from the texture itself being too small, and thus it simply can't handle the speed I set, hence it's blocked at 0.3. I'll try to find a bigger texture that can be used without causing trouble. 

In any case, thank you so much for your insightful help,I'm quite new to this, and it's cool to have such a nice and responsive community !

Answer (score 1):

It is calling your function every frame because you start the coroutine inside of `Update`. See [Update](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) scripting reference.